# TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable while extracting text from scanned PDF

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I have pdf file which contains scanned images from which I want to extract text. I came across this article [here](http://xiaofeima1990.github.io/2016/12/19/extract-text-from-sanned-pdf/) which describes how to achieve it. I have used python extensively on Linux but here I am using Windows 10  platform and I think I have installed all the dependencies correctly. My code looks as follow:

```
from wand.image import Image
from PIL import Image as PI
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
import io
import glob

tool = pyocr.get_available_tools()[0]
type(tool)
lang = tool.get_available_builders()[0]

req_image = []
final_text = []

files = glob.glob("S:\test_data\*")
print files[0]

image_pdf = Image(filename=files[0], resolution=300)
image_jpeg = image_pdf.convert('jpeg')

for img in image_jpeg.sequence:
    img_page = Image(image=img)
    req_image.append(img_page.make_blob('jpeg'))

for img in req_image:
    txt = tool.image_to_string(
        PI.open(io.BytesIO(img)),
        lang=lang,
        builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
    )
    final_text.append(txt)

print final_text
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
S:\test_data\test.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pbhor/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 29, in <module>
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
  File "C:\Users\pbhor\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyocr\tesseract.py", line 365, in image_to_string
    configs=builder.tesseract_configs)
  File "C:\Users\pbhor\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyocr\tesseract.py", line 281, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 599, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 266, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
    txt = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open(img),
    lang=lang,
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
    )
```

Comment: An explanation of why the OP is facing the problem, and how your code fixes it would make this post of far more value (and less likely to attract down / close votes)